# Marionette: unexpected Missing itemViewContainer

Tags: model-view-controller, marionette, composite

I'm getting a 'Missing itemViewContainer' error that I wasn't expecting. My module looks like this:

```
@App.module 'InstagramApp.List', (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class List.ItemView extends Marionette.ItemView
        template: '#instagram_item_template'

    class List.CompositeView extends Marionette.CompositeView
        el: '#bb-instagram'
        className: 'large-3 medium-6 columns projects__project'

        events:
            'click .js-next-photo': 'handleNextClick'
            'click .js-prev-photo': 'handlePrevClick'

        handleNextClick: (e) ->
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log 'next photo'

        handlePrevClick: (e) ->
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log 'previous photo'

        template: '#instagram_list_template'
        itemView: List.ItemView
        itemViewContainer: '#bb-photos-container'
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<script id="instagram_list_template" type="text/template">
    <div class="bg-pattern photos">
        <div class="photos__inner">
            <h4 class="photos__header">I.Instagram</h4>
            <div id="bb-photos-container"></div>
            <a href="#" class="photos__button photos__button--next js-next-photo"><img src="/assets/img/vendor/photos-btn-next.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#" class="photos__button photos__button--prev js-prev-photo"><img src="/assets/img/vendor/photos-btn-prev.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

So my `#bb-photos-container` element is obviously defined... Any thoughts as to what's going on here?

I'm calling it here:

```
@App.module 'InstagramApp.List', (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    List.Controller =

        listPhotos: ->

            photos = App.request 'photo:entities'
            instagramView = new List.CompositeView({ collection: photos })

            $('#bb-projects-list').append(instagramView.render())
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to set el in this instance on `List.CompositeView`

then you can just do

`$('#bb-projects-list').append(instagramView.render().el)`

An even better way would be to define bb-projects-list as a region and then just call

`this.bbProjectsList.show new List.CompositeView({ collection: photos })`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining `el`? If you are appending that view to `#bb-projects-list` I'm guessing you want it to be created from the template, not taken from an existing element.

Try removing that line

`el: '#bb-instagram'`